# arrangedContent not updating when using Ember.SortableMixin and child array

Tags: ember.js

I've created a component to wrap the usage of jquery ui's sortable. I would like to use this component within a controller template by either passing the current model or a child of that model to the content property of my component.

Example usage:

```
{{#sortable-list tagName="ul" content=model.colours as |item|}}
  <li class="sortable-item" data-id={{item.id}}>{{item.sequence}} {{item.colour}} asd</li>
{{/sortable-list}}
```

The component uses Ember.SortableMixin to sort the component on initial load and uses the 'arrangedContent' property to iterate over this sorted collection.

This all works well until I add a new item to the collection, if I've passed the model directly it works as expected, if I've passed a child of the model nothing is updated.

I've created a jsbin as an example - when clicking "Add Colour" I would expect to see a new colour added to both lists, this however is not the case.

http://jsbin.com/wecozawigo/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug, clearly proper observers are not getting triggered. A work around would be force it :

```
App.SortableListComponent = Ember.Component.extend(Ember.SortableMixin, {
  tagName: null,
  classNames: ['sortable'],
  sortProperties: ['sequence'],
  reSortOnContentChange: function(){    
    this.notifyPropertyChange('sortProperties');    
  }.observes('content.length')
});
```

Working jsbin : http://jsbin.com/muyatitudi/1/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because you're mixing it into an `Ember.Component`, which doesn't wrap the content you're passing in in an `ArrayProxy`. This makes it not aware of the change events that the mixin sends out, like `contentDidChange`.

I came across http://blog.yanted.com/2015/03/17/ember-js-quick-tip-3-sorting-array-ember-way/ which might be an alternative workaround.